# In VueJS how to allow input into a form for a specific length of time

Tags: forms, express, vue.js, input, time

I have a VueJS/Express/Postgres app with an input form with a text field.

I want to give my students a question and then give them a specified time in which to answer, at which point, the form should become inactive.

If there is a way to display the timer on the form I would love to do that too.

I have looked around, but not seen any tutorial addressing timed forms.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: The question is too broad, but here's how. Make a request to the server that a question started, then receive a confirmation (and unique question id) from the server, then start the timer, make a request to the server when a form is submitted, validate on server side a form was submitted within time limit for specified question id and respond with success if it did, otherwise respond with an error.